# powershell v2 - how to get process ID

Tags: process, powershell-2.0

I have an Application, that runs multiple instances of itself. e.g

```
AppName.exe instance1
AppName.exe instance2
AppName.exe instance3
```

Using Powershell v2 I am trying to create a simple script that given an array of AppNames and instances, it loops through them, checks if they are running, and then shuts them down.

I figured the best way to do this would be check for each instance, if found capture it's processID, and pass that to the stop-process cmdlet.

BUT, I can't figure out how to get the process id.

So far I have:

```
$appName = "AppName.exe"
$instance = "instance1"

$filter = "name like '%"+$appName+"%'"
$result = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter $filter

foreach($process in $result )
    {
        $desc = $process.Description
        $commArr = $process.CommandLine -split"( )" 
        $inst = $commArr[2] 
        $procID = "GET PROCESS ID HERE"

        if($inst -eq $instance)
            {
                Stop-Process $procID
            }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me where to get the process ID from please?

Comment: this should be simplier :`$pid=get-process appname |select -expand id  `

Comment: I'm still new to powershell but this is why I like it. 15 lines of code reduced to 1.   However, when running it I get the following error -- "Cannot overwrite variable PID because it is read-only or constant"

Comment: Oh sorry this is a built in variable name, you could replace with whatever you want for example `$processid`

Comment: cheers, but I think I am missing something. If I run (for example) `$processid=get-process "explorer.exe*" | select -expand id` `write-host $processid` I can see in Task manager that explorer.exe has PID 3064, but the above script returns nothing.

Comment: try this  `gps explorer` you dont have to write .exe

Comment: I'm making an answer, if you want to accept it so that question will not appears unanswered...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use the get-process cmdlet instead of using wmi  :

`$procid=get-process appname |select -expand id`

Answer (score 7):

```
$procid=(get-process appname).id
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `Get-WmiObject win32_process ...`, the objects returned have an attribute named `ProcessId`.

So, in the question, where you have:

```
$procID = "GET PROCESS ID HERE"
```

use:

```
$procID = $process.ProcessId
```

You could also use that in the $filter assignment, e.g.

```
$filter = "ProcessId=1234"
```