# Powershell v2.0 - find start path and instance and starting an application

Tags: wmi, powershell-2.0

I am trying to write a simple script that stops and then starts a process (Application).

I can stop it fine, but can't find a way to start it again.

The string to start the process should be: `"c:\AppFolder\AppName.exe" instance1`

my script is:

```
$appName = "AppName.exe"
$filter = "name like '%"+$appName+"%'"
$result = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter $filter
$processid = $result.ProcessId 
$command = $result.CommandLine

stop-process $processid

start $command
```

If I run `$result | select *` I see that there is an item for `CommandLine` which is `"C:\AppFolder\AppName.exe" instance1`

But If I try and do:

`$command = $result.CommandLine
stop-process $processid
start $command`

I get `start-process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified`

But if I manually type into a powershell window `start "c:\AppFolder\AppName.exe" instance1` the Application starts fine.

Am I missing something here?

(n.b. it was suggested to me in "[powershell v2 - how to get process ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686547/powershell-v2-how-to-get-process-id/25687253#25687253)" that I could use
`$processid = get-process appName | select -expand id` to get the processid, but when I expanded this to get all the items (probably not the correct term?) 
in the object I couldn't see an option for CommandLine or similar)

---

I found the following (but still doesn't work)

```
$command = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter $filter | select -expandproperty CommandLine
write-host $command
```

This writes "c:\AppFolder\AppName.exe" instance1

```
start-process $command
```

But this then results in the following error:

`Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified
.
At line:11 char:14
+ start-process <<<<  $command
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand`

However, running:

`start-process "c:\AppFolder\AppName.exe" instance1`

starts the application?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it!! (and it's quite simple really) After much googling. . .

Apparently the `start-process` cmdlet only accepts a file location. 
In order to add an argument (in this case the instance name) I need to use the attribute `-ArgumentList`

So I need to get the `CommandLine` item, and split it up, then pass it back in two parts

e.g.

```
$result = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter $filter
$comLine = $result.CommandLine -split"( )"
$comm = $commLine[0]
$inst = $commLine[2] 

start-process -FilePath $comm -ArgumentList $inst
```

And this works as I expected it to.