# PowerShell Get process id using Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    $ComputerName=“comecomputer”,
    $ProcessName = "SomeApp.exe"
     )
$Processes = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -ComputerName $ComputerName -Filter "name='$ProcessName'"

foreach ($process in $processes) 
{ 
    $process
}
```

Above code gets all info about process but there is no clear id.
I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686547/powershell-v2-how-to-get-process-id) post that you can get process id using `$procid=get-process appname |select -expand id` which doesn't work.

Error I'm getting: `get-process : Cannot find a process with the name "SomeApp.exe". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.`

Comment: Have you looked for the ProcessId field?  You may want to do $process | Format-List * if you want to see all the process properties.

Comment: That was really stupid on my side. Thanks

Comment: About your error, there probably isn't anything with that name running?  You can use wildcards for searching like this: get-process "\*someapp\*"

Comment: i used same variable for get-object and get-process and one worked, other didn't

Comment: get-process does work, I use it all the time.  You may want to fiddle with the name and the filtering.  BTW, you can just use get-process to get a complete process list, and then look at what it's reporting as the name.  It is most likely not having the '.exe' on the end.  Don't ask me why, that's just the way it is.

Comment: you were right. extension was wrong